GraphQL Method Not Allowed - Docker Headless Next.JS
I'm getting 405 method not allowed for the layout request in my local developer 10.4 Headless SXA site with Docker.
Backstory - I initially had everything up and running before being forced a Windows 11 update (24H2 26100.2314 - which I believe entails ltsc2025 images), after which my containers could no longer communicate with each other. I followed the answers here - and ended up switching from process to hyperv isoloation, as well as adding hostname's to my containers. I had to use 'hostname: identity' for id and 'hostname:content.management' for cm to finally get everything up and communicating.
Logs from the rendering:
2024-12-20 13:21:31 2024-12-20T19:21:31.936Z sitecore-jss:common page-props-factory start
2024-12-20 13:21:31 2024-12-20T19:21:31.938Z sitecore-jss:layout fetching layout data for / en our-site-name
2024-12-20 13:21:31 2024-12-20T19:21:31.941Z sitecore-jss:layout request: { url: 'http://content.management/sitecore/api/graph/edge', headers: { sc_apikey: 'our-api-key' }, query: 'query {\n' + '      layout(site:"our-site-name", routePath:"/", language:"en"){\n' + '        item {\n' + '          rendered\n' + '        }\n' + '      }\n' + '    }', variables: undefined }
2024-12-20 13:21:33 2024-12-20T19:21:33.274Z sitecore-jss:layout response error: { error: '', status: 405, headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] { 'content-length': [Array] } } }
2024-12-20 13:21:34  ⨯ ClientError: GraphQL Error (Code: 405): {"response":{"error":"","status":405,"headers":{}},"request":{"query":"query {\n      layout(site:\"our-site-name\", routePath:\"/\", language:\"en\"){\n        item {\n          rendered\n        }\n      }\n    }"}}
2024-12-20 13:21:34     at C:\app\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:359:31
2024-12-20 13:21:34     at step (C:\app\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:63:23)
2024-12-20 13:21:34     at Object.next (C:\app\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:44:53)
2024-12-20 13:21:34     at fulfilled (C:\app\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:35:58)
2024-12-20 13:21:34     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
2024-12-20 13:21:34   response: {
2024-12-20 13:21:34     error: '',
2024-12-20 13:21:34     status: 405,
2024-12-20 13:21:34     headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] }
2024-12-20 13:21:34   },
2024-12-20 13:21:34   request: {
2024-12-20 13:21:34     query: 'query {\n' +
2024-12-20 13:21:34       '      layout(site:"our-site-name", routePath:"/", language:"en"){\n' +
2024-12-20 13:21:34       '        item {\n' +
2024-12-20 13:21:34       '          rendered\n' +
2024-12-20 13:21:34       '        }\n' +
2024-12-20 13:21:34       '      }\n' +
2024-12-20 13:21:34       '    }',
2024-12-20 13:21:34     variables: undefined
2024-12-20 13:21:34   },
2024-12-20 13:21:34   page: '/'
2024-12-20 13:21:34 }
2024-12-20 13:21:11 } +1ms

And curl from the rendering:
C:\app>curl -v --location "http://content.management/sitecore/api/graph/edge?sc_apikey=our-api-key" --header "Cookie: our-site-name#lang=en" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{'query':'query {  layout(site: 'our-site-name', routePath: '/', language: 'en') { item { rendered } }\r\n}\r\n","variables":{}}'"
* Host content.management:80 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 76.223.54.146, 13.248.169.48
*   Trying 76.223.54.146:80...
* Connected to content.management (76.223.54.146) port 80
* using HTTP/1.x
> POST /sitecore/api/graph/edge?sc_apikey=our-api-key HTTP/1.1
> Host: content.management
> User-Agent: curl/8.10.1
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: our-site-name#lang=en
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 141
>
* upload completely sent off: 141 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< content-length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host content.management left intact

Ex of docker-compose.override.yml changes
  rendering:
    image: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-rendering:${VERSION:-latest}
    hostname: rendering
    ...
    environment:
      SITECORE_API_HOST: "http://content.management"

  cm:
    image: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-xm1-cm:${VERSION:-latest}
    hostname: content.management
    ...
    environment:
      Sitecore_Identity_Server_InternalAuthority: http://identity

